# What is the best public geoservice for getting data about buildings?

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-server, polygon, modelbuilder, web-service

What is the best public geoservice for getting data about buildings, which is free? Or maybe it's better to ask "does exist such a public service?"

I want to add some 3d polygons to my 3d plane, which I render in WebGL project and I want to get such a service, which may help me with getting detailed information about buildings.

What protocol will respond me an answer on query (WFS or another) - doesn't matter.
I can't google such a service, so ask you in this topic about it.

Comment: Any particular location, city, state/county/  or country?

Comment: @Mapperz for the testing purpose. I prefer [Moscow, Russia], if it's possible, but if it's not, then any. The main goal for me in this: just to try building 3d houses on 3d various geometric shapes. So the exact city isn't an aim.

Comment: Download OpenStreetMap - Buildings are available for Moscow http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=15/55.7561/37.6098 Shapefile available here http://download.bbbike.org/osm/bbbike/Moscow/

Comment: @Mapperz ok, thank you very much! :) why not to post an answer here for you, I shall mark it as the solution, thanks!

Comment: It is not a WFS service but you can create your own from the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Mapperz` has described:

Buildings are available for Moscow:

- http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=15/55.7561/37.6098

OSM, google protocol buffer files, Shapefiles, which are providing data for Moscow, may be downloaded here:

- http://download.bbbike.org/osm/bbbike/Moscow/